# How does “davon” differ from “von denen”?

Tags: difference, preposition, pronoun

> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, **davon** sind zwei Amerikaner.
>
> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, **von denen** zwei Amerikaner sind.

Is the use of *davon* and *von denen* correct in the above sentences? Are there specific cases where one is preferred over the other and vice versa?

Comment: Two suggestions: Replace »In unserem Unterricht« (in our teaching) by »In unserer Klasse« (in our class). This makes more sense. Also mention: A »Student« is an adult person that is inscribed at an university (Universität or Hochschule). If you are not inscribed at an university, than you are a »Schüler«. A »Schüler« is a person that attends a school (Schule). So every person that is too young for university (i.e. younger than 18) is a »Schüler«. Also every adult person that is attending a course at an institution that is not a universitsy or Fachhochschule, is a »Schüler« too.

Comment: But for the second (adult people learning not at university) there is a shift in the meaning of »Student« going on, influenced by Englisch language. More and more people also use »Student« for any adult that is learning something. But still it is better German to use the word »Student« only for learning members of universities.

Comment: I modified your first example to fit the *verb second* rule (davon *sind* …) as it would have been grammatically incorrect, but not part of the scope of the question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Selbst wenn G8 flächendeckend abgeschafft wäre blieben sprachliche Referenzen für minderjährige Studenten, die auch im Ausnahmefall möglich sind, valide, sowie Texte die von Unterricht im Ausland handeln, wo andere Konventionen gelten mögen. Studenten sind nicht immer erwachsen. Theoretischen Unterricht gibt es auch in Fahrschulen, aber von einer Klasse würde ich da nicht reden. Zu meiner Zeit gab es in der Oberstufe keine Klassen mehr, sondern Kurse, so dass man in unterschiedlichen Fächern im Unterricht mit unterschiedlicher Besetzung saß. Was ist mit erw. Berufsschulschül?

Comment: @userunknown: Wer oder was ist hier mit G8 gemeint? Wohl kaum die Gruppe der sieben führenden Industrienationen (G7) plus Russland?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Mehr G9 minus eins: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abitur_nach_der_zw%C3%B6lften_Jahrgangsstufe

Comment: @userunknown ok, das scheint ein Fachbegriff aus dem deutschen Schulsystem zu sein. Das gilt aber nur in einem einzigen Land des deutschen Sprachraums.

Answer (score 3):

> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, davon zwei sind Amerikaner.

uses a wrong word order. It should be

> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, davon sind zwei Amerikaner.

But I'd say it's actually two sentences.

- In our class, we have ten students. Two of them are American.

Whether you use a comma or a full stop to separate the two statements doesn't make a difference:

> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten. Zwei davon sind Amerikaner.
> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, zwei davon sind Amerikaner.

Both are perfectly correct.

The second sentence would translate to

- In our class, we have ten students two of whom are American.

I don't see a difference -- neither in German nor in English.

In summary, the difference between "…, zwei davon sind Amerikaner" and "…, von denen zwei Amerikaner sind" is the same as in "two of them" vs. "two of whom". Some people use this while some use the other. No real difference.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples above the use of both words is possible, however, not completely correct. In number one you would rather say:

> In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten, **zwei davon** sind
> Amerikaner.

In this specific case you can use those two versions and they will both be valid. I will think about another example or a specific case for a different usage. For now, however, I can say that in most cases you will be able to use these two versions.

Comment: Would "In unserem Unterricht haben wir zehn Studenten. Zwei davon sind Amerikaner." be ok? If so, better or worse?

Answer (score 1):

The two fulfil two different grammatical roles.

> In unserer Klasse sind zehn Schüler, davon sind zwei Amerikaner.

As others have already pointed out, these are actually two sentences, two main clauses not connected by a conjunction and thus using a full stop between them is fine. We can thus take the second one by itself.

> Davon sind zwei Amerikaner.

(Other word orders such as ‘Zwei davon …’, are fine too.)
*Davon* in that sentence is a demonstrative pronoun incorporating a preposition of the *da-* class. It is analogous to *daher, dahin, dagegen, darauf* and others:

> Daher weht der Wind.
>   Dahin musst du laufen, um Rom zu erreichen.
>   Du musst deinen Kopf dagegen schlagen, dann geht vielleicht die Tür auf.
>   Du willst darauf klettern?

All of those can be translated by a corresponding preposition and a demonstrative pronoun such as *that*.

---

> In unserer Klasse sind zehn Schüler, von denen zwei Amerikaner sind.

Here, *von denen* is an extended relative pronoun including a preposition. (Note that the preposition is the same as before.) The relative pronoun is slightly more emphasised than others would be. For example, replacing it with *von ihnen, von welchen* etc. puts less emphasis onto the Americans. Note that the second clause is now a relative one and can no longer stand on its own.

Using a preposition followed by a generic relative pronoun as in the example just now is not always considered the best style. Instead, there are special prepositional relative pronouns that are often considered better. In our case this would be:

> In unserer Klasse sind zehn Schüler, *wovon* zwei Amerikaner sind.

This would be the *wo-* type of relative pronouns which can be considered a bridge between the demonstrative preposition-containing pronoun *davon* and the preposition plus relative pronoun *von denen*.

Comment: Könntest du bitte noch einige Bespiele mit **von denen* geben? In einem Film habe ich gesehen, er kaufte Fisch und indem er eine Sorte zeigte, hat er gesagt, **2 Kilo von denen**.  Ist diese Verwendung gleich mit dem Bespiel, das du oben gegeben hast?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Ähnlich, aber anders. »2 Kilo von denen« ist ein Hauptsatz, kein mit *von denen* eingeleiteter Nebensatz. *Denen* ist also ein Demonstrativpronomen, kein Relativpronomen. Ansonsten sind die Rollen ähnlich.